# Ways to predict a continuous variable from a combination of continuous and categorical features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a dataset which contains house prices as well as both continuous features, such as the area, and categorical ones, such as the neighborhood. I would like to build a model which predict house prices (using scikit-learn).

For continuous features there is linear regression and for categorical ones [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression), but what is the recommended way to combine the two?

Answer (score 0):

What matters is the "type" of your dependent variable, i.e., if it is a price then I guess that it continuous. Thus, any linear regression would do the trick. Such models can easily deal with both categorical and continuous independent variables.